# Is there a way within a Quarto document to use the same Global Environment as my Rstudio session?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, quarto

Currently I have to export my data frames out of RStudio to a CSV and then within Quarto use an R code block to load the CSV.  Is there a way to have a Quarto document share the same Global Environment with RStudio?

Comment: No! Each Quarto document run in separate environment different from your global environment and it is for good reason (to make sure the document is reproducible).

Comment: While I understand the argument for reproducibility, the user should still get to decide.  For one off reports, forcing Quarto to use its own environment and having to move the data back and forth is just as inefficient as copying and pasting charts and tables into PowerPoint, defeating the whole purpose of Quarto.

Comment: I agree, for this very reason i moved back to rmarkdown which DOES run the results in the global environment. My use case is I have a master script that processes data then loops thru a vector of every department and runs a flexdashboard rmarkdown with that departments data. I m with JT, the user should decide if they want to run in the global environment or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `source()` to run the scripts for preprocessing the CSVs at the beginning of your Quarto document and use `here::here()` to make accessing files easier.